# Default color for objects is blue. How do i change that?

Tags: color

I installed config for blender and now my default color for objects is blue. How do i change that to standart blender color? 
[image]

Comment: What is "config for Blender"? [Command Config](https://command-config.gg-labs.com/)? Or something else? Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is assuming that the blue is not from an assigned  **Material** Base Color).

If your image is showing your model in edit mode then you can change the default face color in Preferences:

**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Themes** > **3D View** > **Face** > play with color and Alpha values.

[image]

Edited to add:

Ok if its not modified in Preferences .........  in the **3D Viewport** open the **Viewport Shading panel**  > **Color** and if its set to **Random** change to **Material**

[image]

Comment: I checked, face color is dark gray and no materials assigned. Still blue. Added screenshot to the post.

Comment: Have a look in the Viewport Shading panel > Color. If it is set to Random change to Material (see my image above.)

Comment: Thanks you! Changing from random to material color indeed fixed it!